# Handling Arrays of HTML Input Elements with Request.Form Like PHP

Tags: asp.net

How can I properly receive these Array of Inputs on asp.net?

```
<input type=hidden name='field[name][]' value='alex' />
<input type=hidden name='field[name][]' value='mark' />
<input type=hidden name='field[name][]' value='helen' />

<input type=hidden name='field[age][]' value='22' />
<input type=hidden name='field[age][]' value='30' />
<input type=hidden name='field[age][]' value='29' />
```

In php you can access field by `$field = $_POST["field"]`

`$field["name"]` and `$field["age"]` are simply arrays containing names and ages.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

actually, it does exist with asp.net. - you can use

```
string[] MyTest = Request.Form.GetValues("MyTest");
```

or

```
string[] MyTest = Request.QueryString.GetValues("MyTest");
```

Comment: This is the right way, the ASP.NET will do a split for each input posted. Using the String.Split(',') function will be wrong if someone put a string with comma inside (like a address 'New York Plaza, New York, NY 10004').

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know this, I learn something new everyday!

Comment: This should actually be the correct answer. I came across a problem that @charles.art.br mentioned and this was what helped me

Answer (score 4):

You can use a standard string split - this is all php does for you behind the scenes. PHP is not a strongly typed language however which means that it is a LOT easier for them to provide the "appearance" of this functionality.

The reality is that php is just allowing you to provide comma delimited input and it automatically splits it for you.

So... if you want to do this in asp.net, you can use the same input name a number of times and it will be returned with the request object as a comma delimited list. I would not recommend using this approach for user entered input, but it will work fine if you are contrrolling the input like combining a list into a hidden input from a jquery script.

To get your head around what is happening (with php too.. all web dev techs are using the same http rules), just try posting a form with an input (don't set runat server) that is there twice.

```
<input type="text" name="MyTest" value="MyVal1" />
<input type="text" name="MyTest" value="MyVal2" />
```

On pageload add this

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
   Response.Write(Request["MyTest"]);
}
```

You should see

MyVal1,MyVal2

On the screen.

Now, if you want this into an array, you can:

```
string[] myvals = Request["MyTest"].Split(',');
```

if you want Integers or other datatypes (php doesn't know/care what a datatype is really), you will have to loop through it and parse it into another array/generic list.

I don't know what your wanting as an end result, but understanding what the browser posts back is the first step and the short answer is...

Yes, ASP.NET can do this to (just a little more manually).

Answer (score 0):

These are **not** arrays of inputs. HTML doesn't have a concept of arrays.

These are simply groups of inputs with the same name.

What are you trying to achieve? Why are you not using server side controls?

---

Update:

You can access the `Request.Forms` collection - it will hold the posted form elements.

Alternatively, use server side controls - you will be able to access these by ID.

Comment: Hmm i can see now. I changed the subject of question. So PHP does interpret the inputs in a way that gives you an array to work with. So does asp.net have something like that or I need to write my own interpreter? About server side control.. it's more complicated than that since i'm developing my own server controls.