# Asp.net get posted values from an html form in c# using Request.Form an get array value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

```
<input type=hidden name='field[size][large]' value='40' />
<input type=hidden name='field[size][medium]' value='32' />
<input type=hidden name='field[size][small]' value='12' />

<input type=hidden name='field[color][green]' value='22' />
<input type=hidden name='field[color][blue]' value='30' />
```

l have a form like this  how ever l can access values using `Reuest.Form.GetValues("");`

but what am not quit sure is how to get values like in  the form above were the input name for example is   `field[size][large]`

i tried using some example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561686/handling-arrays-of-html-input-elements-with-request-form-like-php) but am not getting the values   if l do a loop on all form values l can see the values   such as

```
    foreach (string key in Request.Form)
                    { 
                        sbError.Append("<br>Key : " + key + "=" + Request.Form[key]);
                        // Do something with (name, value).
// using this will output all form values but l want specifically for field[xxx][xxx] not all
                    }
```

.it will output the value   . my question is how can l get all values in the of the `field[xxx][xxx]`  or loop through them

UPDATE :

am using angular to create the html input values for

```
field['am-created-by-angular']['created-by-angular']
```

so  getting values based on **field** and loop through it and get the values .

l don't know values created by the user on client side using angular , but however there will be alphanumeric  l simply have to capture values

Comment: `Request.Form["field[size][large]"]`?

Comment: @CodeCaster l have updated the question